# Read turkish characters from txt file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read string data from txt file which has special turkish characters in it.

I want to store content in a string. I tried some methods like `textscan` , `fileread` but, instead of special turkish characters like ş,ç,ı,ö,ğ, there are some weird symbols. Are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file called turkish.txt with the characters you mentioned (ş,ç,ı,ö,ğ). Trying to read it gave me the following:

```
fid = fopen('turkish.txt','r','n','UTF-8');
str=fread(fid);
native2unicode(str')

ans =

ÿþ_, ç , 1, ö ,
```

As you can see, ş,ı,ğ are not rendered correctly. If you type

```
help slCharacterEncoding
```

You can see a list of most commonly supported encodings by platforms. I played with the encodings a little, some which I have checked were:

- [ISO-8891-1](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1)
- [US-ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)
- [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)
- Shift_JIS

The last one is related to japanese characters. They contain some of the turkish characters, which were rendered correctly such as ç and ö, but not all of them.

If you skim through the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slcharacterencoding.html) it says:

> If you want to use a different character encoding, you need to start MATLAB with the appropriate locale settings for your operating system. Consult your operating system manual to change the locale setting.

The instructions for setting the locale on windows platforms, which I haven't tried,  can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/setting-locale-on-windows-platforms.html).

Hope it helps.